# What is the algebraic keyword for the fact that $f$ can be split in $h\circ g$ if $\ker(g)\subset\ker(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request

Suppose we have (possibly infinite-dimensional) vector spaces $A, B,$ and $C$. For linear maps $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon A\to C$ such that $\ker(g)\subset \ker(f)$, we have  $f=h\circ g$ for a linear map $h\colon C\to B$, which follows from quotienting $A$ by $\ker(g)$.

As a (regretful) non-algebraist, I would not know where or how to search for analytic properties of $h$ if the vector spaces are normed (/topologic) and $f$ and $g$ are bounded (/continuous).

I would be grateful for either supply of a keyword or a good reference.

Comment: I think "to factor" is typically used. Like "f factors over g"; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57404/meaning-of-a-mapping-factors-over-another On second thought I might have given too much weight to the question in the title.

Comment: thanks a lot. of course. I only could think of "f splits" all the time, but that could not possibly be it.

Comment: One also says that $f\colon A \rightarrow B\,\,$ *factors through* $C$.