# When can I say my 2D mapping is really 1D?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider the following mapping:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}x\\
y
\end{matrix}\right)\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix}x+y\\
\alpha y+\sin\left(2\pi\left(x+y\right)\right)
\end{matrix}\right)$$
with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and the parameter $\alpha\in\left[-1,1\right]$

For $\alpha=0$ this reduces to

$$\left(\begin{matrix}x\\
y
\end{matrix}\right)\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix}x+y\\
\sin\left(2\pi\left(x+y\right)\right)
\end{matrix}\right)$$

I want to say something along the lines of "This is now effectively a one dimensional map", but in what sense is that true? I mean, formally this is still a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
So how can I express this intuition in a more rigorous way?

Comment: What are you trying to say with the phrase “a one-dimensional map” here? With $\alpha=0$, the image of the plane is indeed one-dimensional, but it’s still a map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ as you’ve noted.

Comment: The map "factors through" $\mathbb R$. There are a few questions on the site about the meaning of "factor through".

Comment: maybe consider that the determinant of the Jacobian vanishes everywhere. If it is zero, any 2-d disk is mapped to a zero area patch. Is that "1-d" enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

I will name the functions in the OP. For each $\alpha\in [0,1]$, set $f_\alpha:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ to be given by $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}x+y\\\alpha y+\sin\left(2\pi(x+y)\right)\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $f_0$ reduces to $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}x+y\\\sin\left(2\pi(x+y)\right)\end{pmatrix}$, which has a special property that can be phrased in a few ways.

---

In an informal context, I might simply say "$f_0$ is a function of $x+y$ alone". Speaking to a mathematician, I might also say "$f_0$ factors through $\mathbb R$"*.

To be precise, note that $f_0$ is the composition $h\circ g$ where $g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto x+y$ and $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ is given by $t\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}t\\\sin(2\pi t)\end{pmatrix}$.

*This usage of "factor through" is also attested [in this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57406/26369).