# Is there a name for creating function as follows?

Tags: functions, terminology

Let the function $f$ take values $f(x,y,z)$. Define a function $g$ taking values $g(x,y)=f(x,y,x+y)$.

Is there a name for creating functions such as $g$, whose values are given only by the values of $f$? Can I say that $g$ is induced by $f$?

Comment: There aren’t enough names for all methods of specifying a function. When choosing a name, you need to make sure that it is not occupied

Comment: @AlvinLepik: What sort of trouble are you thinking of? The expression is well-defined as long as $f$ has an appropriate domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ is the "[composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)" of $f$ with $h$ where $h(x,y)=(x,y,x+y)$. With $h$ defined, we could write $g=f\circ h$.

Sometimes, we might say that $g$ "factors through" $f$, but that phrase is a little ambiguous (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57406/26369) for a list of ways that sort of phrasing is used).